# Why did Command + V sometimes become copying on my Mac?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, copy-paste

My device is MacBook Pro M2 running macOS Ventura 13.3.1. The setup is that, I copy "text A" (some words) using <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, I then use the cursor to select a "text B" which I want to replace (with "text A" and I press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>. However sometimes the system does not paste "text A", but copies "text B" instead. If I haven't chosen "text B", then <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> always works well.

Has anyone come across a similar situation? Is it a bug or system feature?

Comment: Which application is this in? Can I confirm that "Paste" doesn't paste, but sometimes copies instead? What keyboard layout (language) are you using? Do you have any third-party clipboard utilities installed?

Comment: Is `edit > copy` and `edit > paste` working?

Comment: The very first diagnostic move to make here is to boot into [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/start-up-your-mac-in-safe-mode-mh21245/mac) to rule out 3rd party tools/utilities that you've installed.  Does the problem go away?